# how can i use predicateWithFormat for two different Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i need to imlement search with to different class ons is Song and the other one is Album. etch one of them is represent song/album with his property (name,url,etc..).
now i am using this code to search song from my songArray by searching the name property, i need to also be able to search in the albumArray, also in the name property.

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {

    // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
    // Remove all objects from the filtered search array
    [self.filteredSongArray removeAllObjects];

    // Filter the array using NSPredicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF._songName contains[cd] %@",searchText];

    filteredSongArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_myDataMgr.songArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}
```

so my qustion is how can i tell the the predicate to look also in the AlbumArray
thank you all.

**UPDATE:**
i ran another predicate on the AlbumArray and after i got the results i added  the two arrays. thank your replay was very helpful!

Comment: Could you run the same predicate on the Album array, then combine both of the filtered arrays? Or combine the song and album arrays then run the predicate on that temporary array?

Comment: Use same property for song name & album name(e.g. _name) in both objects. Get all album & songs object in single array. then apply predicate [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd] %@",searchText]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the array contents like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(songName CONTAINS[cd] %@)", searchText];
[self.filteredSongArray addObjectsFromArray [_myDataMgr.songArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

No need to add SELF in predicate....

Hope this helps...!!!